# Where did using "un servidor" to address yourself come from? / De donde se origina la costumbre de llamerse a sí mismo "un servidor"?

Tags: etimología, pronombres

I've heard from many Spanish-speakers now that when they talk about themselves, they use the phrase "un servidor" instead of "yo" or "mi." I have always thought of the English equivalent of the phrase to be "yours truly."

However, in English, "yours truly" seems to carry a lighthearted, maybe even humorous tone to it, while in Spanish "un servidor" seems much more serious, formal and dignified. Is "yours truly" an accurate translation? Where did the use of "un servidor," a word seemingly rooted in referring to oneself as lowly or humble, come from? Am I correct in thinking that in Spanish this phrase is mostly used in formal contexts?

edit: I've heard it used synonymously with "su/tu servidor"
__

He oído de muchos hispanohablantes ya referirse a sí mismos por "un servidor" en vez de decir "yo" o "mi". En todos los contextos era disertando discursos. Así que, es una practica solo en contextos formales? De donde se origina esta costumbre de rebajarse o humillarse con la frase "un servidor"? En inglés, el equivalente que yo suponía era "yours truly", pero tiene una connotación mucho menos seria o formal (en mi opinión) que la frase en español. ¿Es así realmente? O ¿en qué contextos se usa? ¿Cuál es la etimología de tal frase?

edit: La he oído intercambiablemente con "su/tu servidor"

ejemplos: "¿De quién es este bolso?"
          "De tu servidor"

Comment: Soy nativo de México y nunca he escuchado esa frase.

Comment: I have heard "este servidor", "para servirle", "a su servicio".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

La expresión procede, en efecto, de fórmulas corteses o formales. Por ejemplo, respondiendo a una pregunta:

> - ¿Es usted Pedro Pérez?
> - Para servirle [o *Para servirle a usted*; similar al inglés *at your service*].

En la antefirma de una carta:

> Su seguro servidor [equivalente al inglés *yours truly* o incluso *your humble servant*]

Y, finalmente, al presentarse a una persona:

> - Pedro Pérez, un servidor de usted.

De esta última deriva la expresión abreviada *un servidor*.

En la actualidad estas fórmulas se consideran muy afectadas, por lo que han pasado a usarse de forma irónica, al menos en España. Por lo general, la expresión *un servidor* se usa tan solo coloquialmente, por lo que la traducción sugerida *yours truly* me parece adecuada.

Puede utilizarse *un servidor* o, simplemente, *servidor*:

> - ¿Quién ha dejado aquí este vaso?
> - Servidor [En lugar de, simplemente, *yo*].

De otra forma:

> - Todo esto lo hizo un servidor [En inglés: *All this was done by yours truly*].

Answer (score 4):

Uso:

- Se usa referido al mismo que habla, en expresiones de humildad: *‘Aquí tiene **un servidor** para cualquier cosa que se le ofrezca. Téngame por su humilde servidor’*.

---

Use:

- Is used to refer the same that speaks, in terms of humility: *There is no equivalence in English.*

Note: *Yours truly* is the closest match but only in letters. Not like **un servidor** which can be used in letters and conversations.

Comment: This is interesting... do you have a reference for this?

Comment: I dont have a reference because this phrase is uncommon, when I was living in Cuba I had the opportunity to talk with people that use this phrase.Also, do you speak spanish?

Comment: Yes, I speak Spanish.

Comment: @Flimzy en cuba se usa como explican en la respuesta, ademas recuerdo haberla escuchado en las novelas brasileñas que ponian en Cuba que presisamente era doblada al español por mexicanos

Comment: @syrux un saludo de parte de otro coterraneo, un servidor quien les habla.

Comment: @Flimzy https://www.google.com/search?q=%22un+servidor+quien+les+habla%22&oq=%22un+servidor+quien+les+habla%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.7153j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22un+servidor+quien+les+habla%22

Comment: En España también se usa, yo al menos lo he oído.

Comment: @EmilioGort, Saludos, bueno apreciar como el Español reúne nativos a pesar de la distancia. Un servidor ;)

Answer (score 3):

No sé de donde viene esta expresión, pero posiblemente viene de la biblia.  Hay muchos casos, sobretodo en el antiguo testamento, donde alguien se refiere a si mismo como "su siervo".  "Su servidor" puede ser una variante.

Un ejemplo:

> Josué 5:14  Reina-Valera 1960 (RVR1960)
>
> 14 El respondió: No; mas como Príncipe del ejército de Jehová he
>   venido ahora. Entonces Josué, postrándose sobre su rostro en tierra,
>   le adoró; y le dijo: ¿Qué dice mi Señor a su siervo?

In English:

> Joshua 5:14  New International Version (NIV)
>
> 14 “Neither,” he replied, “but as commander of the army of the Lord I
>   have now come.” Then Joshua fell facedown to the ground in reverence,
>   and asked him, “What message does my Lord have for his servant?”

There is a parallel construct in English.  In the 19th century, it was common to end a letter with the tag line "your humble & obedient servant", followed by the signature.  In the 20th century, this evolved into "yours truly".  In the 21st century, it could evolve into something like "YBFF".  Who knows?

Answer (score 2):

"Un servidor" meaning that person is here for help or assist you in whatever thing you need.

For example when you make a phone call and ask for Juan Perez, the other person says Soy yo un servidor, reference to What can I help you.

---

Cuando una persona se llama asimismo Un servidor, hacer referencia a que esta allí para ayudarlo en lo que necesite. Ya sea en un restaurante, o para ayudar con algún favor.

Comment: Why the downvote to this answer?